# How to set font's kerning in Python Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

For Pillow class **ImageDraw** (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text) I found param **features**. It can tune this font parameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/featurelist

How to set kerning (kern) param? I don't know syntax.

This is not work:

```
draw.text((61, 386), text, (0, 0, 0), font=font, features={"kern": 1.0})
```

Comment: Looks like `features` has to be a list with on/off parameters. So in this case it would be `features=['kern']`. To switch kerning off you have to use `features=['-kern']` . See: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text

Comment: Yes, but how to set kerning value?

Comment: Doesn't look as if you can set a value. It's just on or off.

Comment: "Kerning" is an on/off option. The *values* for each kerning pair are automatically taken from the font. Perhaps you mean "tracking" – increasing or decreasing the distance between *all* characters in a text?

Comment: You can set the kerning in Python using `wand` as here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/71157620/2836621

Answer (score 5):

I hit this same issue recently. I decided the best approach was to draw each letter individually and calculate the space between needed to make it even. This is the code I got it working with.

```
text = "Sample Text"
total_text_width, total_text_height = draw.textsize(text, font=font)
width_difference = desired_width_of_text - total_text_width
gap_width = int(width_difference / (len(text) - 1))
xpos = left_side_padding
for letter in text:
    draw.text((xpos,0),letter, (0,0,0), font=font)
    letter_width, letter_height = draw.textsize(letter, font=font)
    xpos += letter_width + gap_width
```

- `desired_width_of_text` needs to be set and specifies the desired width of the text
- `left_side_padding` should be `0` or specify any padding from the left side
- `font` needs to specify a font in a suitable size

[default spacing vs drawing each letter and calculating spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QppBJ.png)