# Is there a way to adjust letter spacing for text in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, letter-spacing

I wanted to adjust the letter spacing in Tkinter like how it is possible in a document editor but couldn't find anything to change the font style to a more condensed form.

[image: letter spacing example, small and large]

I used Poppins font for some heading, but now I feel like the space between letters is a bit too much.

I couldn't find a font that is similar to Poppins but condensed and also I really don't want to change the font. So, are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71157620/8512262) help at all?

Comment: @JRiggles That answer is related, but it seems to deal with images rather than `tkinter` text. The impression I get from the OP is that they want to do this with actual text, especially since they want to use this for a document editor.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I understand, but some cursory digging indicates that the answer is: "No, you can't do this with tkinter text, but you *can* do it with images - here's how..." (etc. etc.)

Comment: That makes sense, but the solution linked to in that answer seems a little impractical for a document editor, as it looks like it would require a regeneration of the image every time the user typed something. But perhaps we should wait and see what the OP says.

Comment: @JRiggles It seems helpful and I think I can use it for the heading label but I also wanted to use it for the text in a button. So it might get a bit hard for me to work with. Thanks!

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I am sorry I wasn't clear. I was making a different application but having this ability in text would have been better. Hopefully the question is a bit more clear now