# Remove spacing in mutiline text - PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm making a program where I need to draw some text on an image with no space between the lines. I want to use the `multiline_text` function to print one big string with linebreaks, but I can't find a way.

I've tried using the `spacing=0` parameter, but it seems to do nothing. Here is a snippet of my current code. It works, but it's terribly slow.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
import cv2

video = input("Video or image:\n")
img = cv2.imread(video, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
width,height = img.shape
img //= 4
img_list = img.tolist()
asciis = list("""$@B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwmZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft/|)1}]?-_+~>i!lI;:,"^`'.""")
image = ""
for row in img_list:
    row_str = [str(p) for p in row]
    for item in row_str:
        int(item)
        image += asciis[int(item)]
    image += r"\n"
image= image.split(r"\n")

img = Image.new('RGB', (height*6, width*6+4), (255,255,255))
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
for i, line in enumerate(image):
    d.text((0, i*6), line, fill=(0,0,0))
img.save("ascii.jpg", "jpeg")
```

Is there perhaps a better way of doing this?

Comment: Please make sure your code is a [mcve] - that means your `import` statements are present and all your variables have representative values. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry about that. I've fixed the code.

Comment: Well, it's YOU that is placing the text.  You just need to adjust your Y coordinate until the spacing fits your needs. In fact, it looks to me like your code is working just fine.  What's the problem?

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry if my question is unclear. I want a way of calling the multiline text function once and having the spacing set to none. I call the text function repeatedly as a workaround, but this is very slow, hence why I would like to call one multiline_text function. I have updated my question to better fit what I want.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/71155948/839338 it is going to be slow with your long text but it seems to be what you want

Comment: @Dan-Dev That code seems to do what my code already does. My focus is on optimization. If I can find a way to call one text function where the space between lines is 0, my code will be much faster, since I call the same text function for each line in my code.

Comment: It will not be much faster.  Any code that did that kind of spacing will have to do EXACTLY what your code is doing.  Besides, if you're doing ASCII art, surely you want to create a text file, and not an image.  Right?